# Sencha Touch not initializing

Tags: ios, ipad, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

MY sencha touch application is working fine in all browsers, however when I save the url to the iPad home screen. It will not load and only shows a blank screen.  I get no JS errors and nothing comes through the log when debugging.  Heres a sample of the app:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    var rootPanel;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
        viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
        viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=980');
    }
    Ext.application({
        launch: function () {



            var contactForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.FormPanel', {
                standardSubmit: true,
                fullscreen: true,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'My App',
                    docked: 'top'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'LoginName',
                        label: 'Login Name:'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name: 'Password',
                        label: 'Password:'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                        name: 'ReturnUrl',
                        value: '/returnUser.html'
                    }] // items
                }, {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    layout: {
                        pack: 'center'
                    }, // layout
                    ui: 'plain',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Reset',
                        ui: 'decline',
                        handler: function (btn, evt) {
                            Ext.Msg.confirm('', 'Are you sure you want to reset this form?', function (btn) {
                                if (btn === 'yes') {
                                    contactForm.setValues({
                                        LoginName: '',
                                        Password: ''
                                    }); // contactForm()
                                } // switch
                            }); // confirm()
                        }
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Submit',
                        ui: 'confirm',
                        handler: function (btn, evt) {
                            var values = contactForm.getValues();

                            contactForm.submit({
                                url: 'Login',
                                method: 'POST',
                                waitTitle: 'Connecting',
                                waitMsg: 'Sending data...',
                                success: function (form, result) {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Login succeeded!', result.response.reason);
                                },
                                failure: function (form, result) {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed!', result.response.reason);
                                }
                            });

                        } // handler
                    }] // items (toolbar)
                }] // items (formpanel)
            }); // create()
        } // launch
    }); // application()


    $(document).ready(function () {

    });
```

I put an alert in the launch method of `Ext.Application` but it does not show.  When I put it an alert in the `document.ready` function it does show.  I should also note it ***DOES*** work on the ipad browser, just not when launched from the icon on the homescreen.

Comment: Crazy... maybe a caching issue? Not even sure where to start debugging that.

Comment: delete the icon and recreate it, then try

Comment: @jakerella I tried clearing the cache and no luck.  I also tried adding the HTML cache.manifest feature to cache the resources and that didnt work either

Comment: @Mayur  I tried that as well, no luck.

Comment: Is your URL public? Perhaps we should get a verification that this issue exists on another iPad/tablet. I'm wondering if it may be an issue with your device in particular.

Comment: @jakerella I have verified the issue on on a couple devices(2 different gen ipads, iphone5)

Comment: Dang... Have you posted in the Sencha forums? I find the Sencha devs check that pretty regularly. I'm stumped at this point. Sorry!

Comment: Oh, and have you tried removing everything from your `launch()` method except an `alert()` to see if that runs?

Comment: @jakerella  Just tried posting the forums, well see what happens.  Also I tried your second suggestion and the alert never showed :(

Comment: Good luck, I'm very interested to hear if you find a solution. If so, please be sure to post the answer here and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be the version of sencha I was using which was 2.1.0 I believe, as soon as I updated to the latest(2.1.1  Build Date 2013-02-05 12:25:50 ) I works fine.

Comment: @jakerella this was the fix

Answer (score 1):

i faced a similar issue in android actually in my case the problem was because of Ext.Loader not enabled I see you have not included it either. Include this script before Ext.application & see if it works

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled:true
});

Ext.application({...});
```

Comment: Upvote for the idea... I had a similar issue when I started with Sencha. Too bad it didn't work for the OP in this case.